# Equation of a plan through three points?

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain how they got the final answer when they cross product? (10i + 8j + 10k)

[image]

Comment: Like when they get PG x PR they draw that table then get the answer 10i + 8j +10k which is confusing to me as to how they that.

Comment: It isn't a table. It's a matrix, and they are taking a determinant of it.

Comment: @Don, yes, although it's sort of a bogus matrix, since some of the "entries" are numbers and some are vectors. It's an abuse of notation, but it works, and it's memorable, so we use it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True true, but it most certainly ain't a table.

Comment: Try looking up "expansion by minors".  It may also be called "Laplace expansion", ims.

Comment: $i, j$ and$k$ are the unit vectors in the directions of the axes.  So $i=(1,0,0)$ etc.  You work with them as if they were numbers when taking the determinant.  As pointed out this is sort of a caveat.

Answer (score 3):

$10{\hat i}+8{\hat j}+10{\hat k}$ is not the final answer but rather represents the normal vector to the required plane. The "table" you are referring to is a matrix whose determinant give the cross product. While this is the most common way to find the determinant, you could also just simply cross them like this-
$$\bigr(-{\hat i}+5{\hat j}-3{\hat k}\bigr)\times \bigr(-2{\hat i}+0{\hat j}+2{\hat k}\bigr)$$
$$2\bigr({\hat i}\times {\hat i}\bigr)+0\bigr({\hat i}\times {\hat j}\bigr)-2\bigr({\hat i}\times {\hat k}\bigr)-10\bigr({\hat j}\times {\hat i}\bigr)+0\bigr({\hat j}\times {\hat j}\bigr)+10\bigr({\hat j}\times {\hat k}\bigr)+6\bigr({\hat k}\times {\hat i}\bigr)+0\bigr({\hat k}\times {\hat j}\bigr)-6\bigr({\hat k}\times {\hat k}\bigr)$$
$$2{\hat j}+10{\hat k}+10{\hat i}+6{\hat j}$$
$$10{\hat i}+8{\hat j}+10{\hat k}$$
Evidently, the determinant method is easier to do as well as much faster.
To directly get the equation of the plane, it would be best to solve this determinant instead-
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x-2 & y+1 & z-3 \\
    -1 & 5 & -3 \\
    -2 & 0 & 2 
    \end{vmatrix}=0
$$

Comment: As you probably know, once you have the normal vector, you can _almost_ write down the equation of the plane.  $ax+by+cz=d$ is normal to $(a,b,c)$.  To get $d$ is all that remains.  For instance, if you have a point.  This is effectively what _your_ determinant does.  Note, you should set it equal to zero.

Comment: Well, yes but it is still a two step process. My determinant directly gives the equation  by making use of the scalar triple product.